# create a scheduled task that replaces the root page by a static page at a certain time of day

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduled-tasks, handlebars.js

how can I create a scheduled task that replaces the root page by a static page at a certain time of day ?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569621/how-to-schedule-task-with-certain-say-5-hour-period), that sound nice but I could not find something for heroku.

Answer (score 0):

`node-cron` package helps you make scheduled tasks
https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Heroku has background jobs, although it's can be pricey.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

File system access on heroku restricted for /tmp folder, may be this helps you
[How to use heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416738/how-to-use-herokus-ephemeral-filesystem)